# Copy table content to another table in the same database with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Copy table content to another table in the same database with C#.

I got one database (`Baza`) with some data in two tables NEW and OLD. I need to periodically move NEW data to OLD data table (after I do some measuring). I need to compare these data in next step.

I'm using SQL Server CE wit `Baza.sdf` file. In any sophisticated way to copy table to table do it (some loop doing it automatically)?

Thanks

Comment: If you can live with a separate utility (not C# code), you should check out [SQL Compact data and schema script utilty](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/) which allows you to export data as INSERT scripts which you can then run against your target database

Comment: @marc_s, it's about two tables in the same database, your solution seems to me like a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in this way: 
Program reads in loop table NEW row by row and each value changes to parameter. I got 8 columns so 8 parameters(7 integers and one string)
Next each of parameter is inserted to OLD table.
Resuld is also displayed in textBox1:

```
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = \\Program Files\\My         Program\\Program.sdf; Password ='mypassword'");
    conn.Open();
    try
      {
      SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [NEW]", conn);
      SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
          int param1 = rdr.GetInt32(0);
          int param2 = rdr.GetInt32(1);
          int param3 = rdr.GetInt32(2);
          int param4 = rdr.GetInt32(3);
          int param5 = rdr.GetInt32(4);
          int param6 = rdr.GetInt32(5);
          int param7 = rdr.GetInt32(6);
          string param8 = rdr.GetString(7);
          textBox1.AppendText(" " + param1 + " " + param2 + " " + param3 + " " + param4 + " " + param5 + " " + param6 + " " + param7 + " " + param8);
          textBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
          SqlCeCommand ins = new SqlCeCommand("insert into [OLD] values ('" + param1 + "','" + param2 + "','" + param3 + "','" + param4 + "','" + param5 + "','" + param6 + "','" + param7 + "','" + param8 + "');");
          ins.Connection = conn;              
          ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
      }
     catch (Exception msg)
      {
     MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
      }
      conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
insert into [table] (field1, field2) 
    select field1, field2 from [table2] where (your conditions are met)
```

? :-)

Since that's not supported in CE, thanks @marc_s, you could get the records from the `NEW` table using a `select`, then `insert` them into the `OLD` table, and then loop through the initial recordset to delete the rows from the `NEW` by ID for example.

Comment: I did:private void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = \\Program Files\\MyProgram\\Baza.sdf; Password ='password'");
        conn.Open();
        try
          {
          SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into [3GOLD] (ID,X1,X2,X3) select ID,X1,X2,X3 from [3G]);");
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
          catch (Exception msg)
          {
          MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
          }
          conn.Close();
            
        }

Comment: but:       but I got an Error: There was an error parsing the query.[ Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 137, Token in error=)]

Comment: Again: I think it's important to see the OP uses SQL Server **Compact Edition**, which I believe doesn't support anything like this....

Answer (score -2):

Adding to what CodeCaster stated,

Put his code in a storedprocedure and create a job to run on a set interval of your choosing.
You can add logic to the storedprocedure to check the validity of the data as well and set it to notify you if the data was incorrect.  Examples could be given if you included a more specific information in your question.

Comment: I don't think SQL Server **Compact Edition** has support for stored procedures... [see Differences between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx)